# Mac G4 upgrade now has really slow wireless internet!

Tags: mac, upgrade, osx-leopard

This is my computer and model: G4, 1.67 ghz, pre-Intel version.

Here's my problem -- I recently upgraded from the OS it came with, 10.4 Tiger, to the Leopard, 10.5.  Everything works great except the wireless internet sucks.  I've scoured the web and it seems I'm not the first to experience this, but no one has a decent solution.

Question: What is the reason why the wireless connection is slow. Is it possible that the upgrade changed something to make it slow?

Comment: I'm not sure this has anything to do within the realm of stackoverflow.

Comment: Not only is this not programming related, there's no question either. You're hardly new to the site!

Comment: You might have better results asking your question on SuperUser.com.

Comment: haha, yeah actually this is for my friend. I told him this would happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of a couple of reasons:

- Your wireless card is probably 802.11b or g, making it seem slow relative to newer 802.11n
- You have bad internet service or set your computer up in area where it gets bad connection
- The router is pretty new, so it has a tough time dealing with your old computer (or vice versa)

As far as upgrades go, most of these problems can't be fixed by upgrading your existing laptop. Good news, though: netbooks are cheap. Maybe it's time to buy a new laptop? I'm certain that would be cheaper than replacing/upgrading hardware on a legacy Apple (read: expensive) computer.